# Shift-Tab in tmux

Tags: tmux

Currently I have this binding in my `.tmux.config` to go to next window:

```
bind-key -n Tab next-window
```

I would like to make <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycle in the opposite direction. Is this possible?

I tried `bind-key -n S-Tab previous-window`; but this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> should generate a sequence recognized by tmux as `BTab`.

```
bind-key -n  Tab     next-window
bind-key -n BTab previous-window
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realized using ```tab``` this way prevents me from otherwise using this key in a sane way in the terminal. Would you also know how to bind the respective bindings to ```C-x``` and ```C-Shift-y```?

Comment: @LUD If you have a new question then [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). This is [how we work](https://superuser.com/tour). I believe I answered your original question so please see [this](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Okay. I guess I kinda messed up here. Would you say it's less frowned upon to clutter the question feed with a couple of similar questions, than to make small edits to an already answered question (and thereby make the answers to this questions wrong or misleading? Is this the way I should be thinking about it?

Comment: @LUD What I wanted was to avoid a [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310). *One* additional question should be OK. You should not substantially change a question after it is properly answered. If you asked how to bind *a* key, the answer would be `bind-key`, regardless of the key. So changing the key in the question would not matter. But you asked about a *specific* key, *the* key, Shift+Tab specifically (even in the title), your problem was you didn't know `BTab`. This is the problem that has been solved.

Comment: @LUD If you want to avoid asking many separate, similar questions (good thinking), consider asking a more general one. Title: "How to use `bind-key` in tmux with Ctrl, Shift and such?`. Body: "I can do … But now I want to do … or … This leads to the following problem: How can I use both Ctrl and Shift in one binding? Will the modifiers work with any key? What are the exceptions?"